# VSCode ${ inside a React Native <Text> shows error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I must have changed something somewhere in my VSCode because it's showing me an error for this code:
[image]

The code is:

```
<Text>
    ${item.final_price / 100}
</Text>
```

In this case, it should print a dollar value, like "$100" where the $ sign in this case is textual and the brackets here contain a variable.

When hovering on top of the red warning, there's no explanation for the error given. When adding a line break between `$` and `{item.final_price / 100}`, the error is gone, but saving it puts them back together (prettier removes the line break, as it should).

This is probably a tsconfig/prettier declaration which is wrong or something like that. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the error. Also posting code as a picture isn't great.

Comment: Edited the question and added more details

Comment: I doubt there will be any way to diagnose this w/o VSCode/linting/etc. configs.

Comment: `"\`${someValue} can be used like this in js\`"` So prettier understood it like that statement. And removing the line break.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Text>
{"$" + (item.final_price / 100)}
</Text>
```

Comment: I know I can do this. I am not interested in a workaround. I want to understand why I all of a sudden get a parsing error and how to make sure it goes away